# Cassandra keyspace disappeared leading to data loss

Tags: cassandra

I was adding a node (cassandra-03) to my Cassandra 2.1.8 cluster (2 existing nodes, cassandra-01 and cassandra-02, 160+GB each, 1 keyspace), following http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html.

At stage #3 (after restarting each nodes), I realized that on my existing nodes (cassandra-01 and cassandra-02), my keyspace disappeared, but the data are still on the filesystem.

`nodetool status` gives the expected output (3 nodes cluster), except on the data column (I was expecting 160GB on cassandra-01 and cassandra-02), where I only have a few KB.

I moved forward on step #4 and ran `nodetool cleanup` on cassandra-01. It worked in a few seconds, but my keyspace is still missing.

I re-created my keyspace via `cqlsh`, hoping cassandra will use the data sitting on the filesystem, with no luck.

Nothing weird on the logs, as far as I can tell.

How could I get my keyspace data back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the SSTable files in my new keyspace (created with the same name as the original one), so I used `sstableloader` tool to reinject my data into my newly created keyspace (with all the tables created):

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/cassandra/data/mykeyspace /otherlocation/mykeyspace
$ sstableloader -d <host> -f /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml -v /otherlocation/mykeyspace/tablename-<token>;
```